# Fit harmonic model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am relatively new to MATLAB and it's syntax.

In R, we can generate a dataset to model with:

```
> x <- seq(1:100)
> x <- jitter(x,amount=.3)
> y <- seq(1:100)
> y <- sin(y)
> y <- jitter(y)
```

We now have some jittered x values from 1 to 100, and y values which follow approximately a sin curve.

Now we can use `nls` to fit the model:

```
model <- nls(y ~ a + b*x + c*sin(d*x+e), start = c(a=0, b = 1, c = 1,d=1,e=0))
```

Not surprisingly, we get coefficients of approximately 0, 0, 1, 1, and 0.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing in MATLAB.

I have created a text file and loaded in my data from R into MATLAB by using `cat()` to write to a text file. I now have `x` and `y` in MATLAB, both as `100x1 double` objects.

How would I go about fitting the exact same model in the simplest way possible? I do not want to use the curve fitting tool, I know it is visual and simple, but I want to be able to script this.

Basically, in the curve fitting tool, you can type a*sin(b*x+c) and have it fit the model. How can I do this in code?

Answer (score 1):

The function you look for is nlinfit in the statistics toolbox.